# How deny access direct URL to my partial views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some partial views in my controller. The problem is that users can visualize my partial views if they put in url: (www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/mypartialview). How can I deny direct access... and allow work with partial views only from base view?

Thank's!

Comment: are you sure about this?  You need an action method on the controller in order for the view to render - unless you have written a custom action invoker that bypasses the need for an action; or you have a catch-all action that reads the last part of the routed url in as a partial view name.  If either of the last two are the case, we'll need to see how that's done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add [ChildActionOnly] .. like this :

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult List(Model model)
        {...
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andras says, this would only happen if you have a controller action to return them. I can see that you might have those in place in which case you should add the attribute (filter them) as [ChildActionOnly]