# Best practice for views only loaded in via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, view, seo

I am loading a form onto a page via ajax in my Rails 3.2 app. These views are being picked up by Google and the urls just render blank pages. Should I somehow prevent access to these pages when attempting to view from outside my app (http referrer or something like that) or just use the robots.txt file?

Therefore my question is: What is the best thing to do when you have a view which is only ever loaded in via ajax. This is a programming question, as I am happy to code in whatever best practices to my controller files etc. However, it is also from the perspective of SEO and the performance of my app.

I don't want Google to index these pages - however - I don't know if preventing access directly is the best option (such as in this question: [How deny access direct URL to my partial views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409618/how-deny-access-direct-url-to-my-partial-views) <- wrong environment, or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522307/prevent-direct-access-to-certain-urls-only-rails-app-can-load-them <- related but unanswered.)

Of course, I could define these pages in my robots.txt and stop them being indexed, however, maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want Google to index any of your apps pages for what ever reason Ajax or not  I suggest simply using a robots.txt file to Google not to index them.

I'm not aware of a way to block specific partials, Only whole pages.

This would be considered an SEO best practice.

Is there any reason you felt this may not have been the solution? UX? Google TOS?

Comment: I am assuming that this is a very common problem. 

As I am going to then be displaying these pages there will be an associated server load etc. I added the url of the partial to my robots.txt in the end, but thought that possibly there is something more 'railsy'. Thanks a lot for the response. 

Do you know - do the bots check the robots.txt before attempting to crawl - or - are pages crawled then not indexed after the fact?

Finally - Thanks for the answer. I'm all self taught so whilst I 'get it' most of the time I am not armed with a knowledge of all the commonly accepted best practices.

Comment: NP. I'm not sure if the bots crawl or not depending on your robotx.txt. But if you tell them not to index then they won't.